# Share UIWebView between multiple views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oop, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

What I'm trying to do is transfer the contents of a `UIWebView` from one view controller to another. I could just copy the URL and reload the page, but that would take quite a bit of time. Is there any way I could copy the `UIWebView` instance and then render it on an entirely different view? (I've tried making the `UIWebView` object on the second ViewController public and setting it equal to the object in the first view, but I can't seem to get it to work.)
TIA

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this just by adding the web view as a subview on the other view controller's view. If the first UIViewController's view is the web view, then instead you'll want to change it back to a UIView, then add the webview (as its own ivar & property) as a subview.

So incase that made no sense, say viewControllerA has the UIWebView *webView ivar and property, you create the web view as you normally would then add it to viewControllerA's view (probably in viewDidLoad with [self.view addSubview:webView]).

Then in viewControllerB you just call [self.view addSubview: viewControllerA.webView] which will automatically remove the web view from viewControllerA and add it to viewControllerB's view, displaying it to your user.